# multiply multidimensional arrays in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have stored a number of 2d arrays in a 3d array and I need to multiply each one with a vector. so I have stored all those vectors in a 2d array. It's like this:

```
A = np.random.random((L, M, N))
B = np.random.random((L, M))
```

and I need to multiply each A[l] by B[l] which results in a Nx1 array and the output of the whole operation would be a LxN 2d array. Is there a function that can do this or do I need a loop?

Comment: Could you specify what you mean by multiply A[i] by B[i]?

Comment: A[l] is the l-th of those 2d arrays which is a MxN array and l is an integer between 0 and L-1. Likewise B[l] is a 1D array of length M. and I want to multiply transpose of A[l] into B[l].

Comment: Ok, and how is the multiplication of the 1D array with the 2D array defined?

Comment: Normall matrix multiplication. I want to multiply transpose of A[l] which would be NxM into B[l] which would be Mx1 and get a Nx1 array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option is [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html)

```
import numpy as np
output = np.einsum("ijk, ij -> ik", A, B)
```

This results in a (L, N) sized array containing matrix products of all the `A[i].T.dot(B[i])`

Comment: You're welcome. It is worthwhile taking a look at the [docs of `np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html). This function is extremely versatile.