# Multiplying multidimensional array in python

Tags: numpy, python-3.5

I have two arrays:

```
L, M, N = 6, 31, 500
A = np.random.random((L, M, N))
B = np.random.random((L, L))
```

I am trying to get an array C such that:

```
C = B * A

C has dimension  [L, M, N]
```

I tried answer posted at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23527738/multiply-multidimensional-arrays-in-python) but it hasn't given me the desired output.

A for loop version of above code is:

```
L, M, N = 6, 31, 500
A = np.random.random((L, M, N))
B = np.random.random((L, L))

z1 = []
for j in range(M):
    a = np.squeeze(A[:, j, :])
    z1.append(np.dot(B, a))

z2 = np.stack(z1)
```

Comment: If you make the 2 dimensions of `B` different, there'll be less ambiguity.  I don't think you need the `squeeze`.  `A[:,j:]` will be 2d.

Comment: `np.einsum('kl,lmn->kmn', B, A)` should work; but your iterative solution implies a 'mkn' order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [numpy.tensordot()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) where you can specify along which axes to sum:

```
np.tensordot(B,A,axes=(1,0))
```